# Sencha Touch: dialing phone number from sencha application

Tags: sencha-touch

We created a telephone directory Sencha touch mobile application for our company. We have a requirement to dial a employee by tapping the phone number in the employee details screen which should trigger dialing the phone. To achieve the same we used the code highlighted in green color which works in iOS and Andorid Icecream (Tested in older version of Samsung) but failing in Jellybean OS.

Can someone help us how to overcome this or what is the best way to make it work in all the devices.

```
Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem({ xtype: 'adminstaffdetailview', styleHtmlContent: true, html: adminStaffDetailsTemplate,  
            listeners: {  
                tap: function( tap, element ){  
                    if(tap.delegatedTarget.id == 'rowPhoneTap'){  
                        window.location = "wtai://wp/mc;[" + tap.delegatedTarget.innerText.trim() + "]";  
                    }  
                },  
                element: 'element',  
                delegate: 'tr'  
            }});  
        Ext.Viewport.unmask();  
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not using a link with tel protocol instead of a window location to call ?
You need to set data to your tpl (phone_number)

```
Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem({
    xtype: 'adminstaffdetailview',
    styleHtmlContent: true,
    tpl: ['<a href="tel:{phone_number}">call</a>'], // your template adminStaffDetailsTemplate,
});
```